# Shared variable from subreport showing wrong values on crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, sapb1

I have like 3 subreports that have running total values refer [RunningTotal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnl7a.png). There are evaluated so that it only pick unique values and sums those together. So the problem is that on the subreport the value will display for example 205 but when i create a shared formula and add it to the main report i get a value of 206.

This is the formula i used on the subreport:

`WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared NumberVar GrandTotal;
GrandTotal := GrandTotal + {#RTotal1}`

and below is the one i placed in the main report

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared NumberVar GrandTotal;
```

Please assist.

Comment: What is in the formula @AmountZW? May you post a screenshot of the desing of the main report and subreport?

Comment: Hi Heringer. The formula for @AmountZW is simply my ZW field divided by 100 cause its in cents. Most stuff is on page header, a few items that are summarized on the details section.